# Is returning the supplied argument idiomatic in Rust?

Tags: rust, ownership

I have some prototype code:

```
impl MsgTrait for MsgA {
    fn apply_to(&self, state: State) -> State {
        match state {
            State::StateOne(mut state_one) => {
                state_one.common += 1; // just a mutability test
                State::StateOne(state_one)
            },
            _ => {
                state
            }
        }
    }
}

impl MsgTrait for MsgB {
    fn apply_to(&self, state: State) -> State {
        match state {
            State::StateOne(mut state_one) => {
                state_one.common += 2; // just a mutability test
                State::StateOne(state_one)
            },
            State::StateTwo(mut state_two) => {
                state_two.common += 3; // just a mutability test
                State::StateTwo(state_two)
            }
        }
    }
}

// this is a stub for receiving different kinds of messages from the network
fn recv() -> Msg {
    Msg::MsgA(Mega {field_a: 42})
}

fn main() {
    let mut state = State::StateOne(StateOne {common: 0, one_special: 1});
    for _ in 0..100 { // this would be loop, but that makes the playground timeout
        let incoming = recv(); // this would block
        match incoming {
            Msg::MsgA(msg_a) => {
                state = msg_a.apply_to(state)
            },
            Msg::MsgB(msg_b) => {
                state = msg_b.apply_to(state)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e7ddbbe51ce02c66dc3203bc2ecec104

In order to mutate `state` and still have it owned for the next iteration of the loop, I've started returning it from methods.

Is this idiomatic in Rust?

If I do need to do it this way, is there a way to avoid re-wrapping `state_xxx` in `State::StateXxx(state_xxx)` in every method?

Comment: Generally this is pretty common for methods to enable builder patterns and other method chaining. The re-wrapping is necessary depending on what exactly you want to do. One way to avoid verbosity is to implement methods on the enum and have those match and re-wrap.

Comment: If you don't want to rebuild state for every mutation, you could consider passing a mutable reference instead.  eg

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=74a8b1113204bc7abe31f9ced0851fd1

Comment: @possum That's exactly what I was trying to do, I just hadn't included quite enough `mut`s to make it work.  If you make this an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to rebuild state for every mutation, you could consider passing a mutable reference instead. eg

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=74a8b1113204bc7abe31f9ced0851fd1